# dagger 2 module in a dagger 2 component

Tags: android, adapter, dagger-2, android-glide

I'm new to dagger, I decided to use one of my many adapters as training for learning dagger 2, this adapter takes a few objects in its constructor which I've annotated with @Inject

```
@Inject
public CardAdapter(
        ItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener,
        @Named(layoutIdentifierName) String layoutIdentifier,
        TypeFactory typeFactory
        RequestManager glide,
) {
    this.onItemTouchListener = onItemTouchListener;
    this.layoutIdentifier = layoutIdentifier;
    this.typeFactory = typeFactory;
    this.elements = new ArrayList<>();
    this.glide = glide;
}
```

Glide is the one I'm having trouble with I'll come to it last.

First is OnItemTouchListener, It's an interface implemented in my fragment, I've created a module for this. It's an abstract class with an abstract method annotated with @Binds and included in my components (adapters) modules

COMPONENT

```
@Component(modules = ItemTouchListenerModule.class)
```

MODULE

```
@Module
public abstract class ItemTouchListenerModule {

@Binds
abstract ItemTouchListener provideCardHolderFragmentItemTouchListener(CardHolderFragment cardHolderFragment);
```

}

Next is the layoutIdentifier its just a string but it changes at runtime so I've made my component have its own builder and given it a method so I can set this at runtime,

```
@BindsInstance
Builder layoutIdentifier(@Named(layoutIdentifierName) String layoutIdentifier);
```

Next is the TypeFactory, this is an interface, This is another module with an @Binds annotation

```
@Module
public abstract class TypeFactoryModule {
     @Binds
     abstract TypeFactory bindTypeFactory(TypeFactoryForList typeFactoryForList);
}
```

And last, (the one I'm having issues with,) is glide, I'm actually looking to provide the RequestManager, I created a module for it like this

```
@Module
public class GlideModule {

    public static final String glideContextName = "glide context";
    private Context context;

    public GlideModule(@Named(glideContextName) Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    RequestManager provideGlide(){
         return Glide.with(context);
    }
}
```

but if I include this in my components modules and add a method in the custom builder and build it, it gives me an error

```
 error: @Component.Builder is missing setters for required modules or components: [com.sealstudios.simpleaac.dagger.GlideModule]
interface Builder {
```

here is my component, any ideas? also an explanation would be nice i dont think i get everything that happens here, many thanks

```
@Component(modules = {TypeFactoryModule.class, ItemTouchListenerModule.class, 
GlideModule.class})
public interface CardAdapterComponent {

String layoutIdentifierName = "layout identifier";
CardAdapter getCardAdapter();

void inject(CardHolderFragment cardHolderFragment);

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {

    @BindsInstance
    Builder layoutIdentifier(@Named(layoutIdentifierName) String layoutIdentifier);

    @BindsInstance
    Builder itemTouchListenerModule(CardHolderFragment cardHolderFragment);

    @BindsInstance
    Builder glideModule(Context context);

    CardAdapterComponent build();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is with the `GlideModule` constructor argument. Dagger has no idea about how to inject a module's constructor! Either you can explicitly add a component builder method receiving the explicit `GlideModule` object or you can just change `GlideModule` as below,

```
@Module
public class GlideModule {

    public static final String glideContextName = "glide context";

    @Provides
    RequestManager provideGlide(Context context){
         return Glide.with(context);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply pass the context in the component's builder method. Dagger will recognize the `Context` object type and appropriately pass to the `provideGlide` method and it should work as expected.

Comment: great answer thank you, since posting this i switched to hilt and had it working in an hour lol

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is your experience so far? what is it that you like about Hilt but no so much about Dagger? :)

Comment: I already found a bug with scoping view models with constructor injection to a navigation graph but other wise I do find it easier but that maybe due to there being less "information overload" plus I'd just spent the last 2 weeks trying to learn dagger and the few annotations the give you for included modules like application context are nice I haven't got into builders with it yet or scopes really but being able to annotate your android components without having to extend dagger components is nice

Comment: It is incorrect to use any context, or application context universtally.